# Xamarin.Forms CollectionView Infinity Scroll freezed after sometime

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I made a scrolling app with CollectionView with ItemSource=`Photos` and after sometime scrolling the app got freezed.
This is my `ViewModel` counstructor code with all elements:

```
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            CounterData = 20;
            StandartCounter = 20;
            LoadPhotosCommand = new Command(execute: async () => await ExecuteGetAllPhotos());
            LoadRefreshCommand = new Command(execute: async () => await ExecuteRefreshGetAllPhotos());
            LoadNewPhotosCommand = new Command(execute: async () => await ExecuteGetNewPhotos());
            LoadSelectedPhotoCommand = new Command(execute: async () => await ExecuteGetDetailsSelectedPhoto());
            Photos = new ObservableCollection<Photo>();
            PhotosAll = new ObservableCollection<Photo>();
            PhotosModel = new PhotosModel();
            SelectedPhoto = new Photo();
        }
```

This is my logic in the `ViewModel`, and this function  get all photos from the API - store them in the `PhotosAll` list and add 20 elements to `Photos` list which is ItemSource of the collectionView:

```
        async Task ExecuteGetAllPhotos()
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                return;      
            try
            {
                IsBusy = true;
                Photos.Clear();
                PhotosAll.Clear();
                PhotosModel = await InstagramCloneDataStore.GetAllPhotos();
                if (PhotosModel != null)
                {
                    foreach (var photo in PhotosModel.Photos)
                    {

                        PhotosAll.Add(photo);
                    }

                    foreach (var el in PhotosAll.Skip(0).Take(StandartCounter))
                    {
                        Photos.Add(el);
                    }
                    CounterData = StandartCounter;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                var msg = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
```

This is the function from the `RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand` and the logic is when user reach scrolling 20 items read new 20 items and add them to `Photos` list.

```
         async Task ExecuteGetNewPhotos()
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                return;
            try
            {
                IsBusy = true;
                await Task.Delay(100);
                foreach (var el in PhotosAll.Skip(CounterData).Take(StandartCounter))
                {
                    Photos.Add(el);
                }
                CounterData += StandartCounter;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                var msg = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
```

First started to scrolling verywell but after sometime the application got freezed. Does anyone have the same problem? Or have some solution for this?

**UPDATE**
It looks like `Photos` list look bigger the loading new items getting slow

Comment: I faced the same problem while tried to build nested `CollectionView` with several thousands of the items. When scrolling, the application freezes for a few seconds. For myself, I solved the problem by refusing to use `CollectionView` and manual building a view with a combination of `StackLayout`elements. It's not an ideal solution, because I have a start delay when a view is appearing, so it is required to make some kind of virtualization, but this approach is more preferable for me.

Comment: @Miamy can u send some code sample?

Comment: You can find it here: https://github.com/Miamy/MyPlayer/blob/master/MyPlayer/Views/QueuePage.xaml.cs . Pleas note this is very raw prototype which will be redesigned, but you could catch a main idea of the manual view building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of reviewing my code i learn 2 things:

1. RemainingItemsThreshold="{Binding CounterData}" -> CounteData is static value and can't be changed.
2. I implemented one value for skip or u can use CounterData or i use `StandartCounter`, and one value for count the current element position in the big List i caled `RailCounter`.
   In every turn u read from `PhotosAll.Skip(RailCounter).Take(StandartCounter)` and
   `RailCounter += StandartCounter;`
   The problem was CounterData must be static!